# Python - Printing and Classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, methods, printing

I've read more posts and documentation on `__str__` and `__repr__` than is healthy, consulted various texts, and still cannot resolve this printing issue, so I'm putting this out there.

Below is a function I'd like to test.  The code isn't mine, but I would like to know how exactly it works.  I need to see a human-friendly printout of the results (i.e., no hex), so that I can play with it and generally, well, learn something because I truly have no clue how it's doing what it's doing.

```
def get_ordered_adoption_center_list(adopter, list_of_adoption_centers):
    """
    The method returns a list of an organized adoption_center such that the scores for each AdoptionCenter to the Adopter will be ordered from highest score to lowest score.
    """
    list_of_adoption_centers.sort(key=lambda center:center.name)
    list_of_adoption_centers.sort(key=lambda center:adopter.get_score(center), reverse=True)
    return list_of_adoption_centers
```

Below is a relevant cross-section of code that it draws upon, which I did write.

```
import random
import string

class AdoptionCenter:
    """
    The AdoptionCenter class stores the important information that a
    client would need to know about, such as the different numbers of
    species stored, the location, and the name. It also has a method to adopt a pet.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, species_types, location):
        self.name = name
        self.species_types = species_types
        self.location = (float(location[0]), float(location[1]))
    def get_number_of_species(self, species):
        return self.species_types.get(species, 0)
    def get_location(self):
        return self.location
    def get_species_count(self):
        return self.species_types.copy()
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def adopt_pet(self, species):
        self.species_types[species] = self.species_types[species] - 1
        if self.species_types[species] <= 0:
            del self.species_types[species]
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)



class Adopter:
    """ 
    Adopters represent people interested in adopting a species.
    They have a desired species type that they want, and their score is
    simply the number of species that the shelter has of that species.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, desired_species):
        self.name = name
        self.desired_species = desired_species
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name 
    def get_desired_species(self):
        return self.desired_species
    def get_score(self, adoption_center):
        num_desired = adoption_center.get_number_of_species(self.desired_species)
        score = float(1 * num_desired)
        return score
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and score is %d" % (self.name, self.get_score)


class FlexibleAdopter(Adopter):
    """
    A FlexibleAdopter still has one type of species that they desire,
    but they are also alright with considering other types of species.
    considered_species is a list containing the other species the adopter will consider
    Their score should be 1x their desired species + .3x all of their desired species
    """
    def __init__(self, name, desired_species, considered_species):
        Adopter.__init__(self, name, desired_species)
        self.considered_species = considered_species
    def get_score(self, adoption_center):
        num_Other = 0
        for animal in self.considered_species:
            if adoption_center.get_number_of_species(animal) > 0:
                num_Other += adoption_center.get_number_of_species(animal)
        adopter_score = Adopter.get_score(self, adoption_center)
        score = adopter_score + 0.3 * num_Other
        return score
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and score is %d" % (self.name, self.get_score)


class FearfulAdopter(Adopter):
    """
    A FearfulAdopter is afraid of a particular species of animal.
    If the adoption center has one or more of those animals in it, they will
    be a bit more reluctant to go there due to the presence of the feared species.
    Their score should be 1x number of desired species - .3x the number of feared species
    """
    def __init__(self, name, desired_species, feared_species):
        Adopter.__init__(self, name, desired_species)
        self.feared_species = feared_species
    def get_score(self, adoption_center):
        num_feared = adoption_center.get_number_of_species(self.feared_species)
        adopter_score = Adopter.get_score(self, adoption_center)
        score = adopter_score - (0.3 * num_feared)
        return max(0.0, score)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and score is %d" % (self.name, self.get_score)


class AllergicAdopter(Adopter):
    """
    An AllergicAdopter is extremely allergic to a one or more species and cannot
    even be around it a little bit! If the adoption center contains one or more of
    these animals, they will not go there.
    Score should be 0 if the center contains any of the animals, or 1x number of desired animals if not
    """
    def __init__(self, name, desired_species, allergic_species):
        Adopter.__init__(self, name, desired_species)
        self.allergic_species = allergic_species
    def get_score(self, adoption_center):
        for animal in self.allergic_species:
            if animal in adoption_center.get_species_count().keys():
                return 0.0
        return 1.0 * adoption_center.get_number_of_species(self.desired_species)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and score is %d" % (self.name, self.get_score)
```

I've tried placing `__str__` and `__repr__` methods in the various classes.  What I've read suggests `__str__` is what I'm after.  I've also tried placing a simple "for loop" with a print statement in the function body itself. This latter approach lead to a screen full of errors. I've printed using `__str__` before with success, but everything seems to be failing me on this one. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the \_\_str\_\_ code you tried so we can help you debug?

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: You need to show the code that isn't working, along with the complete error message, or the output and an explanation of what's wrong with it.

Comment: Or are you just wanting to know what `list.sort` does? You could print the list there. No need to string the class if you only care about that function

Comment: I'm posting the revised code now.  There is no error message to post with the __str__ methods added to each class.  Rather, I get exactly what I don't want, which is . . .     [<__main__.AdoptionCenter instance at 0x106340f80>, <__main__.AdoptionCenter instance at 0x106348dd0>, <__main__.AdoptionCenter instance at 0x106340758>]

Comment: @Karin -- revised code with str methods posted.  No errors, just info on object existence and memory location.  The error message  File "/Users/ ... /ps7COPY_skeleton.py", line 175, in get_ordered_adoption_center_list
    for ac in get_ordered_adoption_center_list(adopter, list_of_adoption_centers):    were generated when I tried a for loop and print statement in the function.

Comment: @cricket_007 -- That's the ultimate goal, though the printing aspect is very important, so I'm pulling together answers to the other responses. It's taking adoption centers, scores assigned, and somehow knitting them together and sorting them first according to score and, if there's a tie, alphabetically. I don't see how this is possible with lists or why you would use them. I would have though dictionary. I did insert for ac in get_ordered_adoption_center_list(adopter, list_of_adoption_centers): print ac.name, adopter.get_score(ac) in the fxn and got a non-specific error message.

Comment: You should define `__repr__` for the `AdoptionCenter` class.  A list uses the repr of its items, not str.

Comment: Much appreciated, @zondo.  That's good to know and will be useful in other contexts going forward. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, you are printing these within a list. The `print` function retrieves the string representation of each argument to be printed, defined by `__str__`. The string representation of a list consists of square brackets enclosing a comma+space-separated sequence of the `repr` representation of each item, defined by `__repr__`.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __str__(self):
...             return 's'
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'r'
...
>>> l = [A(), A()]
>>> print(l)
[r, r]
>>> print(*l)
s s
```

If you want to see the human-readable string representation of each item, either pass them directly to the `print` function with the `*` unpacking operator, or loop over that list and call `print` on each item. If you want to see a human-readable string representation of each item when you directly print the list that holds them, you can define a `__repr__` that returns the same thing as the `__str__` method does, but it's not recommended, as that's supposed to be a way of reproducing the object with `eval`.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. I will give it a go, when I return to the problem tomorrow. Admittedly, the * operator in a print statement is a new one on me, but then again most thing are new ones on me when exploring the OOP aspects of the language.